# Run a command in a terminal, then when complete leave the command in the terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, xterm

I have a problem where I need to launch a command from a terminal, and leave the terminal open with the command I used once it is complete.  The reason is that depending on certain circumstances I may need to run it again.

I wrote a bash script to run several terminal commands it looks like this

`$ launch.bash /path/to/data`

And the snippet looks like

`xterm -hold -geometry 200x20+2+700 -e "python /home/me/doSomething.py --directory $1; echo python /home/me/doSomething.py --directory $1; bash"`

What this will do now is it will launch the python script and when it completes it will print the command that I used.  It would be nice to print the command into the command line itself, so I can hit enter. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

To reenter the command on the command line is not an easy thing to do (without emulating a keyboard in software, I know of no other way). What you can do is rerun the command when you press enter:

```
while true
do
    xterm -hold -geometry 200x20+2+700 -e "python /home/me/doSomething.py --directory $1; echo python /home/me/doSomething.py --directory $1"
    echo "Press enter to run the command again or CTRL+C to cancel"
    read
done
```

Or you could just press <kbd>↑</kbd> to go back to the last command ran and press enter.